# Assigning data from Scrapy spider to a variable

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm running a Scrapy spider inside a script and I want to assign the scraped data to a variable, rather than output to a file, and read that file to get the data.

Right now the spider is outputting the data to a json file, I then read this data, arrange the data to my needs, and then delete the json file from the spider deleted (mostly because I couldn't figure out how to overwrite the spider output). This works and does what I want but definitely seems pretty brute force, is there a more efficient way that I can access the spider data without having to first output it to a json?

---

This is my code

```
class SpiderManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.run_spider()
        self.compile_json_data()

    @staticmethod
    def write_json(data, filename="quote_data.json"):
        """Write data to JSON file"""

        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    @staticmethod
    def read_json(filename="quote_data.json"):
        """Get data from JSON file"""
        try:
            with open(filename) as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            data = OrderedDict()
        except ValueError:
            data = []
        return data

    @staticmethod
    def compile_json_data(spider_file="quotes_spider.json"):
        """Read the data from the spider & created an OrderedDict"""

        spider_data = SpiderManager.read_json(spider_file)
        spider_data = sorted(spider_data, key=itemgetter("dob"))
        ordered_data = OrderedDict()
        for author_quote in spider_data:
            ordered_data.update({author_quote["author"]: author_quote["quote"]})

        SpiderManager.write_json(ordered_data, filename="quotes_dict.json")
        try:
            Path.cwd() / Path(spider_file).unlink()
        except (FileNotFoundError, TypeError) as e:
            pass

    def run_spider(self):
        """Run the spider"""
        process = CrawlerProcess({"FEED_FORMAT": "json",
                                  "FEED_URI": "quotes_spider.json",
                                  })
        process.crawl(MySpider)
        process.start()


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    temp_data = {}

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        quote_blocks = response.css("div.quote")
        for quote_block in quote_blocks:
            url = quote_block.css("a::attr(href)").get()
            quote = quote_block.css("span::text").get().strip()

            yield response.follow(url, self.parse_crossword,
                                  cb_kwargs=dict(quote=quote))

    def parse_crossword(self, response, quote):
        author = response.css("h3::text").get().strip()
        dob = response.css("span.author-born-date::text").get()
        dob = datetime.strptime(dob, "%B %d, %Y")

        yield {
            "author": author,
            "dob": dob,
            "quote": quote
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpiderManager()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items & ItemPipelines were what I needed to achieve this. I created a class variable in SpiderManager, and then used a pipeline to append each item to the class variable. Below is my code, I added an Item class and Pipeline class, and specified the pipeline CrawlerProcess

```
class SaveItemPipeline:
    """Append item to list in SpiderManager"""
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        SpiderManager.spider_data.append(item)


class MyItem(Item):
    author = Field()
    dob = Field()
    quote = Field()


...


class SpiderManager:
    ...

    def run_spider(self):
     """Run the spider"""
        process = CrawlerProcess({
            "ITEM_PIPELINES": {SaveItemPipeline: 100},
                                  })
        process.crawl(MySpider)
        process.start()
```